# How can I retrieve the image links from this JSON file and put them into an array in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

This is an RSS feed I converted into a JSONFeed. I want to fetch the src images from the feed and put them in an array so I can make a gallery on my website. I'm not sure how to go about that, I've been trying for a couple of hours now.

```
{
  "version": "https://jsonfeed.org/version/1",
  "title": "@plopcosplays on Instagram",
  "home_page_url": "https://www.instagram.com/plopcosplays/",
  "description": "@plopcosplays on Instagram",
  "items": [
    {
      "guid": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7upDfpnv3j",
      "url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7upDfpnv3j",
      "title": "New post",
      "content_html": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7upDfpnv3j\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.97.827.827a/s640x640/82247294_276869959946080_4808220928887701215_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=104&amp;_nc_ohc=YSFVqIXILrcAX-vIKgL&amp;oh=ce551ffd6778fe9b6108755e149e540f&amp;oe=5EC2D6F9\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "summary": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7upDfpnv3j\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.97.827.827a/s640x640/82247294_276869959946080_4808220928887701215_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=104&amp;_nc_ohc=YSFVqIXILrcAX-vIKgL&amp;oh=ce551ffd6778fe9b6108755e149e540f&amp;oe=5EC2D6F9\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "date_published": "2020-01-25T04:12:18.000Z",
      "author": {
        "name": "plopcosplays"
      }
    },
    {
      "guid": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo7wvnp2F",
      "url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo7wvnp2F",
      "title": "New post",
      "content_html": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo7wvnp2F\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.80.640.640a/83113216_172974060600596_984192726141651350_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=IVgVZePX3-wAX8PWWZA&amp;oh=7510619b9d90ef79ceb6bd5af76692c1&amp;oe=5EBFDED3\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "summary": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo7wvnp2F\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.80.640.640a/83113216_172974060600596_984192726141651350_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=IVgVZePX3-wAX8PWWZA&amp;oh=7510619b9d90ef79ceb6bd5af76692c1&amp;oe=5EBFDED3\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "date_published": "2020-01-25T04:11:15.000Z",
      "author": {
        "name": "plopcosplays"
      }
    },
    {
      "guid": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo6ALHuDz",
      "url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo6ALHuDz",
      "title": "New post",
      "content_html": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo6ALHuDz\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.43.340.340a/82248027_472307257005184_4821721743230108514_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=104&amp;_nc_ohc=c1KDOu80WBYAX-1rSNJ&amp;oh=933e1f7827ce80b454a1a2663fa92e4e&amp;oe=5EB710EC\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "summary": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo6ALHuDz\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.43.340.340a/82248027_472307257005184_4821721743230108514_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=104&amp;_nc_ohc=c1KDOu80WBYAX-1rSNJ&amp;oh=933e1f7827ce80b454a1a2663fa92e4e&amp;oe=5EB710EC\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "date_published": "2020-01-25T04:11:00.000Z",
      "author": {
        "name": "plopcosplays"
      }
    },
    {
      "guid": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo3MbH_ZK",
      "url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo3MbH_ZK",
      "title": "New post",
      "content_html": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo3MbH_ZK\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.191.1665.1665a/s640x640/81602613_169174611008169_3858259684707483016_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=109&amp;_nc_ohc=tdXJF2MoHXIAX_LFs_h&amp;oh=65098c92ba086aaf8cb5b0c4d50fed4c&amp;oe=5EB51C52\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "summary": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uo3MbH_ZK\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.191.1665.1665a/s640x640/81602613_169174611008169_3858259684707483016_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=109&amp;_nc_ohc=tdXJF2MoHXIAX_LFs_h&amp;oh=65098c92ba086aaf8cb5b0c4d50fed4c&amp;oe=5EB51C52\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "date_published": "2020-01-25T04:10:37.000Z",
      "author": {
        "name": "plopcosplays"
      }
    },
    {
      "guid": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uorXYndfF",
      "url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uorXYndfF",
      "title": "New post",
      "content_html": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uorXYndfF\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c342.0.1364.1364a/s640x640/82332006_1018840601820006_5789304137732508151_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=106&amp;_nc_ohc=JycZA-8DX9kAX986mSK&amp;oh=690e89508f6b30fa66ffe8ffba7a880a&amp;oe=5EBCC766\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "summary": "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/B7uorXYndfF\"><img src=\"https://instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c342.0.1364.1364a/s640x640/82332006_1018840601820006_5789304137732508151_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frix2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=106&amp;_nc_ohc=JycZA-8DX9kAX986mSK&amp;oh=690e89508f6b30fa66ffe8ffba7a880a&amp;oe=5EBCC766\" width=\"640\" height=\"640\"></a>\n\n<br/><br/><span style=\"font-size:12px; color: gray;\">(Feed generated with <a href=\"http://fetchrss.com\" target=\"_blank\">FetchRSS</a>)</span>",
      "date_published": "2020-01-25T04:09:01.000Z",
      "author": {
        "name": "plopcosplays"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I've tried so far. It only renders 3 or so broken images.

```
import React from "react";
import GalleryModal from "./gallerymodal.js";
import "../../assets/css/now-ui-kit.css";

var Feed = require('rss-to-json');

Feed.load('http://fetchrss.com/rss/5e2cba6c8a93f8714b8b45675e2cba408a93f8e54a8b4567.xml', function(err, rss){
    console.log(rss);
});

const imgUrls = [];

for(let item in Feed){
  imgUrls.push(item.url);
}

class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentIndex: null };
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    this.findNext = this.findNext.bind(this);
    this.findPrev = this.findPrev.bind(this);
    this.renderImageContent = this.renderImageContent.bind(this);
  }
  renderImageContent(src, index) {
    return (
      <div onClick={(e) => this.openModal(e, index)}>
        <img src={src} key={src} alt="pic" />
      </div>
    ) 
  }
  openModal(e, index) {
    this.setState ({ currentIndex: index });
  }
  closeModal(e) {
    if (e !== undefined) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    this.setState ({ currentIndex: null });
  }
  findPrev(e) {
    if (e !== undefined) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentIndex: prevState.currentIndex -1
    }));
  }
  findNext(e) {
    if (e !== undefined) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentIndex: prevState.currentIndex + 1
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="gallery-container">
        <div className="gallery-grid">
          {imgUrls.map(this.renderImageContent)}
        </div>
        <GalleryModal 
          closeModal={this.closeModal} 
          findPrev={this.findPrev} 
          findNext={this.findNext} 
          hasPrev={this.state.currentIndex > 0} 
          hasNext={this.state.currentIndex + 1 < imgUrls.length} 
          src={imgUrls[this.state.currentIndex]} 
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

  export default Gallery;
```

I've also tried using the original RSS feed xml but I get this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://fetchrss.com/rss/5e2cba6c8a93f8714b8b45675e2cba408a93f8e54a8b4567.xml' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var requestOptions: RequestInit = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
      };
      const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
      
      fetch(CORS_PROXY + "http://fetchrss.com/rss/5f56c6803c140278522985135f56c72f61579219a908f6e2.json", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Try adding the CORS_PROXY bit as it worked for me. I found the fix in the rss-parse npm module docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser